# How to detect when an inner PreferenceScreen has been closed

Tags: android, preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I have a inner PreferenceScreen (call it `Users`) inside another PreferenceScreen (call it `Main`).
When i tap `Users` a new screen opens and I can change my Preferences there (a lot of CheckBoxes).
I want to detect (fire a callback) when this screen is dismissed and when I'm back on the `Main` PreferenceScreen.
The only way I found is to create a new class inheriting PreferenceScreen and overloading `onPrepareForRemoval`

I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do that.

Comment: use `onDestroy` to recognize when its closed?

Comment: `onDestroy`detects when the `Main` PreferenceScreen is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very interesting question!
I finally figured out.

The trick is to set `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` for the `PreferenceScreen`  submenu (`Users`, in our case) and you can do it in `onPreferenceTreeClick` (as here internal `Dialog` is already initialized). So `void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)` is the callback you've been looking for.

Here's the `xml\preferences.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="main">
    <EditTextPreference android:title="Your Name"
        android:key="username"
        android:summary="Please provide your username"/>
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="users"
        android:title="Users"
        android:summary="Click here to select users">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="User 1"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="user1CheckBox" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="User 2"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="user2CheckBox" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:title="User 3"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="user3CheckBox" />
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here's the `PreferenceActivity` and `PreferenceFragment` I used:

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
            if (preference instanceof PreferenceScreen) {
                PreferenceScreen submenu = (PreferenceScreen)preference;
                submenu.getDialog().setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        Log.d("MainPreferenceFragment", "Hi! Submenu is closing now!");
                    }
                });
            }

            return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
        }
    }
}
```

#### UPD: Solution for `PreferenceFragmentCompat`:

First, we need one more xml: `xml\subpreference.xml` (duplicate of the submenu from the main `preference.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="users"
    android:title="Users"
    android:summary="Click here to select users">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="User 1"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="user1CheckBox" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="User 2"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="user2CheckBox" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:title="User 3"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="user3CheckBox" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Then, our hosting activity should `implements PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartScreenCallback`. And last step - we need a new subfragment (or pass exact XML you need to inflate as a bundle's parameter):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartScreenCallback{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new MainPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceStartScreen(PreferenceFragmentCompat preferenceFragmentCompat,
                                           PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new SubPreferenceFragment()).commit();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

    public static class SubPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.sub_preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

It this case, you can just listen to normal `onBackPressed()` of Activity

I hope, it helps

Comment: This works pretty well. However, what if the PreferenceScreen is android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen? As support library version of PreferenceScreen, doesn't have getDialog.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng  I've added solution for support library also. Check it out!